# Django ManytoManyfields error `AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'dev_id'`

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I guess there is already been a lot of discussions available almost went through all of them but still facing this error.

```py
class Device(models.Model):
    """Storing Device ids """
    platform  = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=PLATFORM, default = 'ANR')
    dev_id    = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null=True, blank=False)
​
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user             = models.OneToOneField('user.User', 
                                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                         related_name='profile',
                                         primary_key=True,
                                         unique=True)
    device           = models.ManyToManyField(Device, related_name='devices')
​
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

> Error 1

```py
username = UserProfile.objects.filter(
                    phone_number=user_username).get()
username.device.dev_id
*** AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'dev_id'
```

> Error 2
> *After Some Research*

````py
username.device.values_list('dev_id', flat=True)
<QuerySet []>
​```

There is no device found with this user but there are devices in them for this username
For the reference, I have listed devices

```python
>>> Device.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Device: 1>]>
````

> Error 3

```py
(Pdb) username.device.all()
<QuerySet []>
 Checked with this Method but not able to list devices
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This cannot work, because `device` is a `ManyToMany` Relationship.
A user can obviously have multiple devices (or none) associated.

If you want to access all devices from a user, try the following:

`user.device.all()`

this will give you a `QuerySet` from a `RelatedManager`. Just use it like a regular `QuerySet`:

```py
for d in user.device.all():
  print(d.dev_id)
```

This, of course, is described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: Actually, you were correct there was ```no device at all associated with the user``` What I missed was I created the objects independently but did not add ```device``` into ```userProfile``` Thank you for the explanation and linking documentation.